# Index not created in jdbc river plugin (elastic search)

Tags: elasticsearch

New to world of elastic search.I am trying to connect elastic search to mysql db using jdbc river plugin.
Query Used:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
    "url" : "jdbc:mysql://local/test",
    "user" : "",
    "password" : "",
    "sql" : "select * from orders ",


}
}'
```

Exception Observed :

```
[ERROR][river.jdbc.BulkNodeClient] cluster state is RED and not YELLOW, cowardly refusing to continue with operations
java.io.IOException: cluster state is RED and not YELLOW, cowardly refusing to continue with operations
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.client.ClientHelper.waitForCluster(ClientHelper.java:85)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.client.node.BulkNodeClient.waitForCluster(BulkNodeClient.java:411)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.client.node.BulkNodeClient.newClient(BulkNodeClient.java:205)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.river.JDBCRiver$1.create(JDBCRiver.java:237)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth.setIngestFactory(SimpleRiverMouth.java:88)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth.setIngestFactory(SimpleRiverMouth.java:45)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.createRiverMouth(SimpleRiverFlow.java:304)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.beforeFetch(SimpleRiverFlow.java:184)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.execute(SimpleRiverFlow.java:148)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.request(RiverPipeline.java:88)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.call(RiverPipeline.java:66)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.call(RiverPipeline.java:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2015-02-19 10:39:20,175][INFO ][river.jdbc.SimpleRiverMouth] creating index jdbc with settings {} and mappings null
[2015-02-19 10:39:20,175][ERROR][river.jdbc.SimpleRiverFlow] client is closed
org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchIllegalStateException: client is closed
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.client.node.BulkNodeClient.newIndex(BulkNodeClient.java:473)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.client.node.BulkNodeClient.newIndex(BulkNodeClient.java:53)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth.beforeFetch(SimpleRiverMouth.java:106)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.beforeFetch(SimpleRiverFlow.java:207)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverFlow.execute(SimpleRiverFlow.java:148)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.request(RiverPipeline.java:88)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.call(RiverPipeline.java:66)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.plugin.jdbc.RiverPipeline.call(RiverPipeline.java:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can someone help fix this issue?

Additional info : 
Elastic search version :-1.4.2
Plugin version:-1.4.0.9

Comment: Why is your cluster red? Have you recently shut down a node with indexes without replicas? With a plugin like kopf it's easy to visualize indexes and to see which shards haven't been allocated.

Answer (score 0):

you could install a plugin named "head".

```
cd $ES_HOME/bin
./plugin -install mobz/elasticsearch-head
```

then you can view it in a web browser by visiting http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head . It's easy to see the status of shard.